# Simple JS search function for website doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, html

I am putting in a simple search function with JS on my website, and it doesn't appear to work anymore - it was working fine before the weekend, but I think it's because I've put too many 'if' arguments in. For example, customer would search XLR, and it would reload on the same page the XLR category.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>Tuto</title>
</head>


<body style=" background-color: rgb(4, 41, 255);">
<input type="search" value="" id="search" onchange="openPage()">

<script>
    function openPage() {
        var x = document.getElementById("search").value;

        if (x === "Oyaide") {
            window.location.replace("/Products#!/oyaide/sort/manual");
        }
        
        if (x === "oyaide") {
            window.location.replace("/Products#!/oyaide/sort/manual");
        }
        
        if (x === "OYAIDE") {
            window.location.replace("/Products#!/oyaide/sort/manual");
        }

        if (x === "Opus") {
            window.location.replace("/Products#!/opus-collection/sort/manual");
        }
        
        if (x === "opus") {
            window.location.replace("/Products#!/opus-collection/sort/manual");
        }
```

(and so on, with about 50 entries)

Do I need to group them into variables? I have just listed

Comment: Sorry, was meant to put on the end 'I have just listed that way to easily pick out and put in products over time' 

Many thanks

Comment: Do you get any js errors in console?

Comment: You're *really* doing things the hard way. [Open the browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), look for error messages – most likely you changed something that introduced a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Angel, no errors with validating

Comment: FYI: you can just do `x.toLowerCase()` this way you don't have to add if statements for all the different ways of typing a category

Comment: Seems like a typo, but either way this is a really bad way of implementing a search-bar.

Comment: Hi Guy, actually on console, it says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
2Products:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: openPage is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (Products:109)

Comment: Hi Reyno, thank you

Comment: Well then you have an error on line 109 (or somewhere near it)

Comment: Hi Guy, will check it out

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "no errors with validating", I've asked if any errors in the debugger ? If your code was working, and stopped working at some point, probably is because some syntax error or something...

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: openPage is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange" - check your syntax

Comment: Hi guy, I didn't add a ; ! :')

Comment: Sorry Angel, presumed you meant in notepad++ before put and not the debugger

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably a typo and definitely out of your snippet. I just want to show you an easier way to make the mapping between search value and URL, using a map/object:

```
const sites = {
  'oyaide': '/Products#!/oyaide/sort/manual',
  'opus': '/Products#!/opus-collection/sort/manual',
  // ...
};

function openPage() {
   const x = document.getElementById("search").value;

   if(sites[x.toLowerCase()] != null) {
      window.location.replace(sites[x.toLowerCase()]);
   }
}
```

But even that is not optimal and I would highly suggest you to make a simple search function with suggested results, like for example google does it. It is pretty easy to implement and the user does not have to type the whole word to get to his result this way.

Comment: Hi Maurice, I'm just doing it for page load time posterity instead of fetching from google or a CMS, thank you for your answer

Comment: I am not saying that you should fetch anything from google. I just said that you should take an example of already successful search-bars and try to see what they do right and what they offer. Then implement that into your own platform. For example the user should not have to input the whole string to find his result, but rather a few letters and you should then show him possible results. @AlexanderBeswick

Comment: Hi Maurice, that is very true. I am going to have a 'preview' hover in due course.

Comment: yeah well not with your solution using 50 if's. @AlexanderBeswick

Answer (score -1):

On your page, change

```
<input type="search" value="" id="search" onchange="openPage()">
```

to

```
<input type="search" id="search" />
```

In your `<script>`, add the following:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('change', openPage);
})
```

Using inline event listeners is considered malpractice, for a whole bunch of reasons.